# Cannot set .color property in JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button id="change_button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ColorMe()">CLICK ME</button>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Clicking a button is supposed to color all the elements of class "grid_element" into red but in never happens.

```
function ColorMe() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("grid_element").style.color = ("red");
}
```

The problem is said to be Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
    at ColorMe (js.js:2) but I know it worked in the same way many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to use the `.style` property on the collection of elements found by `.getElementsByClassName()` instead of on each of the elements within the collection.

Also (FYI), `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list, which causes the entire DOM to be re-scanned every time you access the node list variable and that can impact performance quite a bit. There are limited use cases for that, so you probably want a "static" node list more often than not. For that, use `.querySelectorAll()`.

```js
function ColorMe() {
  // Get all the matching elements into a JavaScript Array
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".grid_element"));
  
  // Loop over each element....
  elements.forEach(function(el){
    el.style.color = "red";  // Adjust the element's style
  });    
}
```

```html
<button id="change_button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ColorMe()">CLICK ME</button>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="grid_element">
                    <div class="title">
                        COLOR IS:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @lesha_ber I just updated the answer and fixed a typo.

Comment: Not OP here.  You have the right answer as far as I can tell, but I'm curious: why did you convert the nodeList into an array rather than using `Array.prototype.forEach.call` on the nodeList?  I don't think one way is very preferable over another; just curious.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Your technique doesn't convert the node list to an array and not all browsers implement `.forEach()` on node lists or will allow node lists to be enumerated via `.forEach()`, so your code may not even work in some clients. Even if it does, using my technique, and assigning the result to a variable allows me to keep the results in an array for as long as I want to, in case I want to do other array operations on the results (maybe loop a second time later). Your technique would require you to continuously do conversions every time you want an array operation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You're correct.  Using the forEach prototype would not convert it to an array but keep the HTMLCollection items as their original type.  Thanks for taking the time to explain the rational.  I thought it might have to do in part with possible future manipulations using array methods, but that didn't occur to me at first.  I love seeing multiple approaches to solving a single problem because there usually is a nuanced reason behind the individual decisions. Thanks, again!